# Android - Facebook SDK installed but can't use Facebook button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have installed the Facebook SDK and have login set up, but I am just using a basic button I made when I use the button they say to use, this one:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/facebook_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I get this Runtime Error?

```
3650-3677/com.spencerfontein.ueat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
```

Not sure why this is happening. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks for the help in advance?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing this in my android manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```